# How to deploy war file in Filezilla FTP?

Tags: ftp, war, filezilla

How to deploy war file in Filezila FTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filezilla is only for uploading the WAR, not deploying it.  Use Filezilla to connect to the server via FTP.  Find your application server's web apps deployment directory (for instance, in Tomcat this is often the "webapps" directory).  Upload the WAR file there.  Then follow the deployment instructions for your particular application server.

Comment: Thanks sir..i got a clarification