# Upload WAR file to an FTP server

Tags: java, web, war, filezilla

I've just finished a web project, working with Struts2, and now I want to add this project to my FTP site. The site runs smoothly on Tomcat 8, but I am not sure how to deploy it to an actual site.

How do I add this `.WAR` file that has `.jsp` and `.xml` files to a website? I've tried to just put it in a directory and launch it with fileZilla, and it doesn't work.

What should I do to launch my Struts2 project to my FTP site?

Comment: Put it in the `webapps` folder of your tomcat.

Comment: You can't just run it from an FTP server. You need to have a web server installed first. You cannot launch it from Filezilla, it needs to be ran on an actual web server

Comment: @Ascalonian What web server would you recommend? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnPulple - You're already familiar with Tomcat, so why not use that?

Comment: @Ascalonian How do I run Tomcat to my FTP site? I'm familiar using Tomcat with eclipse, and launching it there, so how would I do it to launch Tomcat to my FTP? Sorry if the questions are dumb, and thanks for the time to answer.

Comment: [Apache Tomcat 8 Setup](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In `FileZilla` put your user name and password.
2. In left side will show your machine file
3. On right side put path of your `webapp` folder, It will come in mail when you buy any server from hosting providers or ask them.
4. Upload your `.WAR` file in `webapp` folder.
5. Restart Tomcat.

Comment: How do I do the first step? I can't see a webapp folder in my FTP server that I am launching from FileZilla.

Comment: answer is edited, you have to check at right side of file zilla, or check with your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to deploy it again on your FTP site. You need to deploy it into your webapps folder of your server. You may look at this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup). This might help you :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Would you mind explaining a bit further? I don't have a webapps folder on my FTP site. Should I create one, or what do you mean? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnPulple i assume in your ftp path, you will have your tomcat server installed. If you open the tomcat installation folder you will find a webapps folder. Place your war file there and then restart your server. This will deploy ur war file. In case if it is not there (chances are neglible) then create a webapps folder inside ur tomcat installation and repeat the above process.. Hope this clears your query a bit!!!

Comment: I don't think I have my tomcat server installed to my ftp path. Because all I got right now, is a website (with just plain html on), a .war file, and a tomcat server to my Eclipse. I have no idea how to connect my tomcat to my actual server on FileZilla. How do I do that? Thanks for your response.

Comment: @JohnPulple You may look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921307/how-to-deploy-war-file-in-filezilla-ftp?rq=1